# VMWare Workstation - vmware-hostd - Anyone know why this is needed and why if I leave VMWare open it uses up 30% of my cpu consistently?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I keep having to end the process even though I may just have the app open with no OS running.  I've never had the issue before so not sure what is causing it.  I'm on Windows 8.1 if it helps.

Comment: VMware is a company. What VMware product are you running?

Comment: I've updated it.  Workstation or Player gives me the same problem

Comment: Is Windows 64-bit? Which VMware Workstation version are you using? When was last time you weren't experiencing this issue? Have you got any restore points?

Comment: I can't remember the last time I didn't have the issue unfortunately.   It is on Windows 8.1 64bit plus VMWare 10.  I did notice there was an update this month so I have upgraded to that while waiting to see if that addresses my issues

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's needed to use the Shared VMs feature of VMware Workstation to access VMs remotely.  If you don't need it, then you can disable it by going to Edit > Preferences > Shared VMs > Disable Sharing.